# For loop not working on my Query Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck in a project which I need to get the data from document in a collection. I'm currently using Firestore for Android Studio. The fact is that my query shows the toast just after the `task.isSuccessful` but the `For` loop is not getting the data from the Cloud, not even showing the test Toast I put inside the loop. Everything works fine till get to the `For` loop. The `RecyclerView` only shows content if I put parameters manually
 for test so Adapter is working fine but when I try to show the data from the firestorm it shows nothing! Any idea? It does not show any error!

```
public class MostrarConteudoFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    List<Compras> listaCompras = new ArrayList<>();
    Compras compras;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    SavedFragment savedFragment;
    public String idUpdate = "";  // id do item para o update


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_conteudo_fragment);


        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance( );
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser( );
        recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        savedFragment = new SavedFragment();


    }

     protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    if(listaCompras.size() > 0)
        listaCompras.clear();

    db.collection("Usuario").document(user.getUid()).collection("ItensSalvos")
            .whereEqualTo("id", idUpdate).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MostrarConteudoFragment.this, "task succcessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult( )) {

                            Toast.makeText(MostrarConteudoFragment.this, "doc succcessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );

                            compras = new Compras(doc.getString("id"),
                                    doc.getString("inputNome"),
                                    doc.getString("inputQtd"),
                                    doc.getString("inputPreco"),
                                    doc.getBoolean("checkBoxOk"));

                            listaCompras.add(compras);

                        }

                        //Configurar adapter
                        AdapterMostrarConteudo mostrarConteudo = new AdapterMostrarConteudo(MostrarConteudoFragment.this, listaCompras);


                        //Configurar RecyclerView
                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext( ));
                        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
                        recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        recyclerView2.setAdapter(mostrarConteudo);
                    }   
                }
            });



}
```

}

public class AdapterSave extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
List<DataHora> listaDataHora;
SavedFragment savedFragment;
MostrarConteudoFragment mostrarConteudo;


public AdapterSave(SavedFragment savedFragment, List<DataHora> listaDataHora) {
    this.savedFragment = savedFragment;
    this.listaDataHora = listaDataHora;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_salvas, viewGroup, false);

    mostrarConteudo = new MostrarConteudoFragment();

    return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

    myViewHolder.data.setText(listaDataHora.get(i).getData());
    myViewHolder.hora.setText(listaDataHora.get(i).getHora());

    myViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

            mostrarConteudo.idUpdate = listaDataHora.get(position).getId();

            Intent intent = new Intent(savedFragment.getActivity(), MostrarConteudoFragment.class);
            savedFragment.startActivity(intent );

            Toast.makeText(savedFragment.getContext(), mostrarConteudo.idUpdate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );



        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaDataHora.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    TextView data, hora;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

        data = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textData);
        hora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textHora);

    }

    // Metodo construtor da interface ItemClickListener
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;


    }

    @Override     // Permite abrir o menu com o click
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);

    }


    @Override        // Cria o menu quando item é clicado
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {


    }
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvAYG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqnL4.png)

Comment: You say `my query shows the toast just after the task.isSuccessful` but where in your code are checking that? Please also add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: Sure, i just added!

Comment: I'm sorry but I still not see the code where you are using `task.isSuccessful`. Please indicate which toast is actually working. Also what does `idUpdate` that you are using in your reference return?

Comment: It should be here but i took it off and didn't see:        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {                      
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MostrarConteudoFragment.this, "task succcessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );
      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {

Comment: But even when it was on didn't work and the STRING idUpdate returns the id of another recycler view , so when i click on the item it should get the id of it and put into the idUpdate, this idUpdate i use to compare to it's list and open  in the recycler view that i not getting to work. It's all working fine but when try to open the list into the recyclerview2 it's not showing. The For loop in MostrarConteudoFragment.class is not getting any data.

Comment: Solved! Just a "s" missing on my collection. I can't believe i did this!!!

Comment: Good to hear that, cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!! @Alex Mamo